# Is this code considered as a recursion?

Tags: c#, recursion

I have endless process that work with the next logic (notice the circle between `ServiceUtilities_OnReSubscribing` to `timer_Elapsed`) - when exception is raised in ServiceUtilities_OnReSubscribing, it's create a new timer `t` and in the finish" event of 't', a call to ServiceUtilities_OnReSubscribing is scheduled.

I'm wondering how C# stack is behaving in this case, is it considered a recursion?

```
    System.Timers.Timer timer;
    readonly object timerLocker = new object();

    void ServiceUtilities_OnReSubscribing()
    {
        lock (timerLocker)
        {
            try
            {
                 //do something
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //do somehing...
                timer = SetTimer();
                timer.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CleanTimer(timer);
        ServiceUtilities_OnReSubscribing();
    }


    private System.Timers.Timer SetTimer()
    {
        int miliSeconds = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReSubscribingTimer"], out miliSeconds) == false)
            miliSeconds = 3000;

        if (miliSeconds <= 1000)
            miliSeconds = 3000;

        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(miliSeconds);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        return timer;
    }

    private void CleanTimer(System.Timers.Timer timer)
    {
        timer.Elapsed -= timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Dispose();
    }
```

I want to avoid a scenario which my stacktrace gets full due a many recursive calls.
Is this code considered as recursion?

Comment: Which timeout you read from configuration?

Comment: There is no recursion and you can don't worrying about stack overflow exception.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan `ServiceUtilities_OnReSubscribing` calls `SetTimer` calls `timer_Elapsed` calls `ServiceUtilities_OnReSubscribing` (with a delay). If I didn't missed something, this code is recursive. There are two types of recursion: direct and [indirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Indirect_recursion). In case of indirect method `A` calls `B` ... which in the chain calls again `A`. I would argue, that this is indeed a recursive code. But this won't blow the stacktrace, because timer would be called with a new stacktrace.

Comment: Even though this code is *logically* recursive, there is no risk of overflowing the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `timer_Elapsed` method is called from the timer thread, so it is not on the same call stack as `ServiceUtilities_OnReSubscribing`.

Therefore you don't need to worry about your stack overflowing, as the call stack won't grow.